# Does Xcode have a graphic editor

Tags: xcode

ALL,

Looking for a way to create a cursor inside an Xcode.

Google gives nothing in this regards - it just produces a lot of un-useful links, even for SO.

I'm looking for something like a Resource Editor in MSVC, where you can create a bitmap/menu/cursor, save it and then later use it in your program.

If the answer is - Xcode doesn't have a graphic editor - then what can I use to create a cursor {custom} file

EDIT:

```
Igors-MacBook-Air:minimal igorkorot$ ls -la
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  41 root  wheel  1312 Apr 12  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  42 root  wheel  1344 Jul  4  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 busybutclickable
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 cell
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 closedhand
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 contextualmenu
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 copy
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 countingdownhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 countingupandownhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 countinguphand
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 cross
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 help
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 ibeamvertical
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 makealias
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 move
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 notallowed
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 openhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 pointinghand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 poof
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizedown
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeeast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeeastwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeleft
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeleftright
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenorth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenortheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenortheastsouthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenorthsouth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenorthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizenorthwestsoutheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeright
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizesouth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizesoutheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizesouthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeup
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizeupdown
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 resizewest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 Apr 12  2018 screenshotselection
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 screenshotwindow
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 zoomin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Apr 12  2018 zoomout
```

First - I don't see a `pdf` extension, so how do I know it is in `pdf format?

Second - not all of them are here. In particular I don't see a `hand`
cursor file...

Thx for the pointer nevertheless.

Comment: Glad you already got the answer. You can search free cursor PNGs on Google.

Comment: There are any number of vector drawing apps - Affinity Designer, Graphic, Inkscape...

Comment: @benwiggy, are you saying that by default Mac can have an SVG as a cursor file?

Comment: No, they are usually PDFs. See the contents of `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors`  Most other icons are PNGs, and have to be created at several different sizes, so exporting from a vector original makes sense.

Comment: @benwiggy, see my edit...

Comment: @Igor You have included a list of what's inside the folder. No, they don't have a PDF extension because they're not PDFs - they're folders. So if you open up any of those folders - for example "resizeup" - you'll see there's a PDF file inside.

Comment: I have the feeling that there's something you're not telling us that would be worthwhile to know. Are you a software developer? - Are you trying to develop a macOS application or background service? - For what purpose are you trying to change the cursor? - What do you mean exactly by cursor? (do you mean the graphics displayed on screen to indicate where text would appear if you press the keyboard, or do you mean the graphics displayed on screen to indicate where the mouse is currently pointing?) - Have you decided on an API to use for changing the cursor?

Comment: @jksoegaard, yes I'm a software developer. Yes I'm trying to develop the application for OSX, Windows and Linux.  Purpose - I want my cursor to be shown. The meaning is mouse cursor (the second portion). Yes I did.

Comment: Hehe, I meant _tell_ us which API you’re going to use. When I know that, I can tell you how. There’s multiple ways of doing this depending on API choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode does not have a built-in editor for creating and editing graphics files.

Instead use any graphics editor that works with the file format you want to use (for example PNG). A free option could be [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org).

Comment: thank you. I feared that much. ;-) Do you know what file type is the cursors on OSX? I know in Windows it is `cur`? Is it different? Does GIMP supports this type?

Comment: It's usually in PDF format on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Growly Draw is a free graphics editor - both pixel and shapes. I've used their other apps, which work well.  https://growlybird.com/draw/